# Where was the operation Market Garden UK planning headquarters?

Tags: world-war-two, united-kingdom

Can someone remind me of the name of the house and country estate in southern England where much of Operation Market Garden was planned. I have even been on a course there in the 1980s, but can't remember or find it online.

Comment: Please tell us where you have looked already.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I have heard of books. But there are also people willing to be helpful and polite, without point-scoring. I was not asking casually whether anyone could refresh my memory, not asking them to write my dissertation for me. Online culture is so welcoming and friendly, isn't it. Thanks to those who tried to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stoke Rochford Hall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoke_Rochford_Hall), Near Grantham, Lincolnshire

Comment: Thanks, that was the place. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which specific component you are referring to:

The First Allied Airborne Army was headquartered at [Sunninghill Park](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sunninghill+Park/@51.4211526,-0.6480235,13z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x5923539677811b06!8m2!3d51.4251333!4d-0.6495659) under the command of [Major General Louis Brereton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_H._Brereton#First_Allied_Airborne_Army).

- The [U.S. XVIII Airborne Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XVIII_Airborne_Corps#World_War_II) was headquartered at [Ogbourne St. George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogbourne_St_George) under [Major General Ridgeway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Ridgway).
- Detailed planning for Operation market Garden in particular wad done primarily by [British First Airborne Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Airborne_Corps_(United_Kingdom)) as it was a supercedence of an earlier and less ambitious *coup de main* - Operation Comet. Location of its headquarters escapes for the moment.

Comment: Thanks, but those are not the locations I meant. I recall lots of photos of airborne troops and commemorative displays. It was described as the main UK planning location for the overall Market Garden operation.